# bounty deduction at start or end of period?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

[GBThm_PhysicsProof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064929/gauss-bonnet-theorem-proof-considering-membrane-force-and-hydrostatic-fluid-pres)

I started the bounty for a week. Is it deducted normally right away or after one week?

Comment: The bounty amount is deducted immediately from the bounty giver's reputation.

Comment: You can also check this in your profile [on the reputation tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/95860/narasimham?tab=reputation). Links to more detailed info about bounties [can be found here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info).

Comment: Thanks, found it.